# Memory Usage Estimation or Calculation

Tags: web-server

I have a web application I would like to host on a server that currently hosts other applications and processes. I plan to use Session Authentication for this app so memory use will need addressed. The applications currently on the server and my new application make use of MySQL. For the new application the total number of concurrent sessions is likely to never exceed 100.

I need to find a method to help calculate the current memory usage on the server as well as the impact the new application may have.

The only information I can currently gather is the amount of memory used to store session variables. Once I have that for one session I simply multiply by the max number of expected sessions. This is only a small part of the picture.

I will also need to know how much memory is used while MySQL is handling queries. Which will vary depending on the number of running sessions.

Along with that I will still need to know the current memory usage on the server.

Additionally I plan to manage session ids in a strict setting so the database will also be utilized for that.

I understand there are a large number of factors that play into this. What Im hoping to find here is a methodology of how I can gather more information about my current usage to see if this server will be able to handle more memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all that information it's better to install  "MySQL Enterprise Monitor" 
using this tool you will have a lot of information about performance, memory usage, disk usage, query,etc,etc all this information in real time.
This will help you to take the appropiate desitions and adjust configuration variables and evaluate the performance.

Comment: Does this require a licence for the Enterprise version? I currently use community

Comment: Yes it's under license, however  "MySQL Enterprise Monito"r can monitor both Community and Enterprise MySQL server releases.